# Different results in CodeBlocks and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++

I used CodeBlocks to code this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream is;
    is.open("game.inp");
    int n,a[100];
    is>>n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        is>>a[i];
    is.close();
    int game[100];
    int kt=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=3; j<a[i]+1; j++)
        {
            if ((a[i]%j)==0)
            {
                int *x = find(begin(game),end(game),j); //ktra uoc hien tai da co trong mang hay chua, k co thi ms them
                if (x==end(game))
                {
                    game[kt]=j;
                    kt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int kq=0;
    for (int i=0; i<kt; i++)
    {
        int d=0;
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if ((a[j]%game[i])==0)
                d++;
        }
        if (d>kq)
            kq=d;
    }
    ofstream o;
    o.open("game.out");
    o<<kq;
    o.close();
    return 0;
}
```

and the result was not correct. Then I decided to copy these codes to Visual Studio 2019 and it gave me the correct result. I don't know what happened. I copied the same codes from CodeBlocks to VS and the results were completely different.

Comment: You really should check for errors on all of your input. It could fail and you'd never know it.

Comment: Maybe the file was not even opened. Your code does not check if the file was read or not. It proceeds regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You use the contents of the array `game` *before* it's initialized. Local variables are not initialized, their contents is *indeterminate* and using indeterminate values lead to undefined behavior.

If you want the array to be initialized to all zeroes you need to do it explicitly:

```
int game[100] = { 0 };
```

Comment: You are right, now CodeBlocks also gave me the correct answer. Thank you bro

Comment: So does that mean VS 2019 will automatically initialize my array?

Comment: Depends, some compilers can initialize variables in debug mode on their own, to make debugging easier, but it's not something you should rely on.

Comment: In debug mode `Visual Studio` it fills stack memory with `0xcc` and heap memory with `0xcd`. Also the OS may fill the memory it gives your process to avoid information leaking from process to process.